# Is there a way to get the name of the npm script passed to the command specified by that script?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, npm-scripts

With npm or yarn, is it possible for the script specified by an npm script to know the name of the npm script itself? For example:

```
"scripts": {
  "foo": "echo Original command: $0",
  "bar": "echo Original command: $0"
}
```

I'd like the result of those two scripts to be something like:

```
Original command: yarn run foo
Original command: yarn run bar
```

But all I actually get is: `Original command: /bin/sh`.

And in case it makes a difference, it's just the name of the script I need, not the `yarn run` part, so output like `Original command:  foo` would be fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

NPM adds the `npm_lifecycle_event` environment variable. It's similar to [package.json vars](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#packagejson-vars).

#### **Nix* (Linux, macOS, ... )

On **nix* platforms npm utilizes `sh` as the default shell for running npm scripts, therefore your scripts can be defined as:

```json
"scripts": {
  "foo": "echo The script run was: $npm_lifecycle_event",
  "bar": "echo The script run was: $npm_lifecycle_event"
}
```

***Note:** The dollar prefix `$` to reference the variable.*

#### Windows:

On Windows npm utilizes `cmd.exe` as the default shell for running npm scripts, therefore your scripts can be defined as:

```json
"scripts": {
  "foo": "echo The script run was: %npm_lifecycle_event%",
  "bar": "echo The script run was: %npm_lifecycle_event%"
}
```

***Note:** The leading and trailing percentage sign `%` used to reference the variable.*

#### Cross-platform (Linux, macOS, Windows, ... )

For cross-platform you can either:

1. Utilize [cross-var](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-var) to enable a single syntax, i.e. using the dollar sign prefix `$` as per the **nix* syntax.
2. Or, utilize the node.js command line option [`-p`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_p_print_script) to evaluate and print the result of the following inline JavaScript:

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "foo": "node -e \"console.log('The script run was:', process.env.npm_lifecycle_event)\"",
     "bar": "node -e \"console.log('The script run was:', process.env.npm_lifecycle_event)\""
   }
   ```

   ***Note** In this example we:*

   - *Access the `npm_lifecycle_event` environment variable using the node.js [process.env](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env) property.*
   - *Utilize [`console.log`](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console_log_data_args) (instead of `echo`) to print the result to `stdout`*

Comment: This will only work if your command performs a single action. If you have pre/post commands, `npm_lifecycle_event` will point to the last command. To get the original command, one can read from `process.env.npm_config_argv` which is a JSON string containing the `original` property, which is the command ran before any `pre` and `post` scripts.